# compute $\int_\gamma F\cdot dr$ using Stokes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

> Evaluate
> $$ \int_\gamma F\cdot dr$$ where $ F=(ye^x,e^x+x^3,z^5)$ and $ \gamma\ $ is the intersection between $x^2+y^2=1 $ and $z=2xy$ oriented in such a way that the orthogonal projection on the $xy$ plane is oriented counterclockwise.

Here is how I have tried to solve this problem:
I used Stokes and first calculated the curl of F which is $(0,0,3x^2)$ and then  doted this with unit normal but it become zero, however the answer should not become zero.

What am I doing wrong ?
Any suggestion would be great , Thanks

Comment: You have not written down the parametrization of the surface or the normal vector. So difficult to say what went wrong.

Comment: You can choose any surface for which $\gamma$ is the boundary. If you choose a surface which is a part of the cylinder, the surface integral is indeed zero, but $\gamma$ can only be a part of the boundary of that surface. So you've only shown that the line integral along any curve that goes around the cylinder once (with the same orientation) is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameterize the surface as $ \ r(\rho, t) = (\rho \cos t, \rho \sin t, \rho^2 \sin2t)$

$0 \leq \rho \leq 1, 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

$r_{\rho} \times r_{t} = (2 \rho^2 \sin t, 2 \rho^2 \cos t, \rho)$

$\nabla \times \vec{F} = (0, 0, 3 \rho^2 \cos^2t)$

So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (0,0,3 \rho^2 \cos^2t) \cdot (2 \rho^2 \sin t, 2 \rho^2 \cos t, \rho) \ d\rho \ dt$

$ = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 3 \rho^3 \cos^2t \ d\rho \ dt = \frac{3 \pi}{4}$

Comment: Thank you @Math Lover, I have 2 stupid questions , 1_ Which direction does this normal vector point towards? and is that compatible with the curve? i mean how should i know these? my second question is why sometimes when we parameterize the surface (not changing variable, just parameterizing a surface) for example in sphere we keep radius as it is (a constant number) but another times we write $a<\rho<b$ like in this case, is it because the radius keep changing?

Comment: Your second question first - usually when you have to integrate over surface area, you parametrize using two variables. Which two variables depends on which plane you are taking projection of the surface in and that depends on the surface and what is easier to work with. In cylindrical coordinates, for example, if we have to parametrize surface of a cylinder along $z-$axis, we parametrize using $\theta$ and $z$ keeping $r$ constant.

Comment: Now take a real-life example, say, surface of a mushroom. I can parametrize its surface such that $z$ is written in terms of values of $x, y$ because for any given value of $x,y$, there is only one point on its surface and so one value of $z$. Now when I look at it from top, I see a circular projection on the ground and every infinitely small area of its projection corresponds to an area on the surface. Once we know that relation, we integrate it over the area of the circular projection and that gives its surface area. In cylindrical coordinates, we will parametrize using $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Specifically for a sphere, if we are parametrizing in spherical coordinates, we keep $r$ constant as we parametrize using $\theta$ and $\phi$. In cylindrical coordinates, we do parametrize using $r, \theta$ if we are taking projection in any of the planes but that projection is of a hemisphere. Same in cartesian - we can parametrize using $x,y$ or any two of them and that projection is of a hemisphere.

Comment: On normal vector, what we have chosen is a positively oriented surface which is an outward normal vector. So yes it should match with the counter-clockwise orientation of the curve given in the question. For orientation of surface vs. of curl (microscopic circulation) vs. of boundary curve in Stokes' Theorem, below may help - https://mathinsight.org/stokes_theorem_orientation.

Comment: The curve is oriented counterclockwise but if we choose outward pointing normal then we should walk in clockwise direction near the curve in order to surface to be on the left hand side, am i wrong ? and how should we know with this parametrization that which direction does normal pointing?

Comment: That would have been true if the outward normal vector was pointing downward like in a paraboloid (with $z \geq 0$) with vertex at $(0,0,0)$ and we had a boundary curve at, say, $z=3$. Our head would be pointing downward in the direction of the normal vector and then for the surface to be on our left, we would have to walk clockwise. In this case, as our curve is on the cylinder, walking anti-clockwise on the curve will match with positive orientation on the surface.

Comment: I have no words to thank you enough, you have helped me a lot, thank you very much and sorry that i took your time

Comment: @simon you are welcome